# How do I add to the file i created on my android app?

Tags: java, android

this is my code:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("things", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
fOut.write(thing.getBytes());
```

everytime i go through this method it erases the previous data in the file and overwrites it with the new one. I don't want this to happen because I want the text to be added Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does `openFileOutput` do? Assuming you're creating a `FileOutputStream` in there, you can pass a boolean to make it append instead of overwrite. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File, boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Add the flag [**MODE_APPEND**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_APPEND) :

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("things", MODE_APPEND);
fOut.write(thing.getBytes())
```

other option would be using of course the `append()` method:

```
 FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile,true);
 OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
 myOutWriter.append("Something new!\n");
 myOutWriter.close();
 fOut.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to add (bitwise OR) the [MODE_APPEND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_APPEND) flag to the MODE_PRIVATE one in the openFileOutput call